# Dual boot with Windows 7, Ubuntu 12.10 boots to grub

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop and I cannot get it to boot. I created a primary partition for `/` that is 20480 MB large and a partition for `/home` that is 202124 MB. 12.10 installs without any errors. I have no issue rebooting into Windows 7 but when I try to boot into Ubuntu it just boots to a GRUB prompt.

Please advise.

System info:

```
HP DV7t-7000
16GB RAM
512 SSD 
Partitions:
    198MB NTFS Primary - EUFI Boot
    250GB NTFS Primary - Windoes C Drive
    19.07GB SWAP
    19.07 Ext4 Primary - /
    188.51GB Ext4 Logical -  /home
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using boot-repair to rebuild the grub install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

It will prompt you to do a some stuff while it's running, but this will fix it.

Also, did you set a /boot ?

Comment: I did not make a a /boot partition I just pointed it to / when I installed it

Comment: Hm, you may want to make a /boot partition, I had some issues as well when I set it up with / as the boot part. when dual booting Win7